# Does SVN retain knowledge on a per-user basis?

Tags: svn

There are ways to find such information using log, but does SVN have a direct way to get information about a user? Like their last commit, commit history, etc - any kind of reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion do not retain such knowledge, you have to grab it yourself.

To get all commits from an user you can try the [methods described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499910/how-to-display-a-specific-users-commits-in-svn-log).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TortoiseSVN that can provide some of user statistics.  In TortoiseSVN ->Repo-browser, right click the folder that contains all project files, and select "Show Log" and then click "Statistics" button.